# I'm having trouble starting Steam, could someone help?

Tags: steam

When I try to load Steam, I end up with the error: `You are missing the following 32- bit libraries, and Steam may not run: libgl.so.1`

It also says that steam needs to install these additional packages:

- libgl1-mesa-dri:i386
- libgl1-mesa-glx:i386
- libc6:i386

I was just wondering if anyone could help me with installing Steam.  If you need any more information from me please ask and I'll do my best to get it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try this.

```
 install wine proabaly
```

and enter this in the terminal:

```
 sudo apt-get update
 sudo apt-get install wine
 sudo apt-get install wine1.7 winetricks
```

and when it show the screen push enter, and it might work fine this way

Comment: I was unable to find a reference to the switch "probaly" or, assuming it's a typo, "probably".  Is that a switch for installing Wine?

Answer (score 0):

You can easily fix this by opening a terminal and runing the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 libc6:i386
```